# Run button in Visual Studio gives options for manage.py instead of running

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, manage.py

I am trying to run a Django project with manage.py as the startup file. I can run it fine from command prompt using `python manage.py runserver`and manually navigate to the site. I am expecting that when I press the run button in Visual Studio that it will start the server and open my browser to show me the page, but instead it just opens the options for manage.py:

```
Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
changepassword
createsuperuser
```

etc.

I've tried re-setting manage.py as the startup file, resetting the startup project, and setting the startup script for the Python Tools Interactive Windows to manage.py.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you set the project up in VS as a Django project? Else, all the run button simply does is `python manage.py` which will naturally show all of those options

Comment: Someone else made the project and set it up as a Django project. They (as well as others on my team) can run it and it starts the server just fine, but when I clone the project and try to run, all it shows are these options. @MosesKoledoye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't have a launch mode set for Debug. I went into `Project-> 'Project-name' Properties... -> Debug tab`. I saw that I didn't have a `Launch mode` selected from the drop down menu. I selected `Web launcher`, and now everything works the way I was expecting.

Comment: Thank you I was havin this problem too, don't know how it got deselected tho well is working now :)